# Is it possible to add ODBC service to existing CF 2016 install?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

We are migrating some code from CF 10 to CF 2016 virtual machines that needs to connect to a couple Access databases. I installed the necessary drivers and setup odbc datasources in Windows but have found that our CF 2016 VM was setup without the ODBC service and I have not been able to find a clear way to add it.

When I go to add/remove programs the only option is to uninstall CF and when I run a CF 2016 installer it will not let me go through the "Server configuration" process because an existing install already exists. Is there a standard approach for adding sub-components to a CF server that were not chosen on first install?

Comment: I don't remember, but I think Access has trouble with the 64-bit drivers. And I know this is way off topic, but is it possible to migrate those Access databases to another database? Access is great for a desktop database, but it always causes trouble when it's connected to externally. :-/

Comment: SQL Server gets easier and easier to setup too.

Comment: These Access databases are uploaded and processed for data updates. Everything else is SQL Server. I have started converting the simple processing code from CF to Python which should eliminate the need for this question. Considered various options to connect to Access files in SQL Server.

Comment: You say, you installed the necessary drivers. Which are these? There's a JDBC driver for access. You can try that. https://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files/

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I followed steps I found for setting up Access datasources in CF2016 which involved installing MS provided drivers and creating Windows ODBC datasources. If we had a more major need I would continue with trying other options but just going to move on with python for now. I have added an answer to this question that I found involving Charlie Arehart and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I found my answer after digging around for a while. The migration wizard needs to be run again to add the ODBC service but there could be various complications with this depending on permissions and other factors. I was not able to get this to work after a brief period of time so I am just going to wrap up my transition to using python for our limited Access needs but I do believe this to be the answer.

https://community.adobe.com/t5/ColdFusion/ColdFusion-11-ODBC-service/td-p/6207226

Here are the basic steps. **See link above for various troubleshooting info from Charlie Arehart and others.**

1. Navigate to adminconfig.xml at C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\lib\ and open it with text editor (say notepad).
2. Change the value from “false” to “true” in runmigrationwizard
3. Change the value from “false” to “true” in odbc
4. Save the file and restart ColdFusion Service.
5. After restarting the service, access the cf admin url and you will get the migration wizard. Follow the onscreen wizard to continue.

I came upon the answer by way of a [thread about getting Access data sources setup in CF11 and CF2016](https://community.adobe.com/t5/ColdFusion/create-data-source-for-microsoft-access-on-64-bit-server-and/td-p/8212154#8676379) which Charlie Arehart contributed to and linked over to info about the ODBC service setup.